# Group Separator Delimiter with ^]

Tags: c#, x12

We are sending 270 message to third party system. But they are expecting Group separator as ^] as a single character in the message and the same for others also How do I do that ? Not sure how this be done in c#

```
1D-GS- GROUP SEPARATOR-DATA ELEMENT SEPARATOR
1E-RS- RECORD SEPARATOR-REPETITION SEPARATOR
1F-US- UNIT SEPARATOR-SUBSEQUENT SEPARATOR
1C-FS- FILE SEPARATOR-SEGMENT TERMINATOR
```

Here is some reference http://www.astrohandbook.com/files/ascii_codes.html

Comment: `var s = "STRING" + (char)29 + "STRING"`

Comment: @AntonGogolev - Thank you. That is working.